# Are vitamins supplements required for young children?

Tags: nutrition, medicine

Do I need to add vitamin supplements to my 4-year-old's and 2-year-old's diet? Currently they like pasta, noodle, cheese, rice, carrots, broccoli, chicken and eggs. I'm wondering whether B group supplement will benefit them since their father's side had some B deficiencies before. Does general vitamin supplements for toddlers do good?

Answer (score 2):

Children between 6 months and 5 years should take a daily supplement of vitamins A, C, and D.

If you live in England and are on a low income you are entitled to free vitamin supplements.

http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/pregnancy-and-baby/pages/vitamins-for-children.aspx

> That’s why the Department of Health recommends that all children aged six months to five years are given vitamin supplements containing vitamins A, C and D every day.
>
> It's also recommended that babies who are being breastfed are given a daily vitamin D supplement from birth.
>
> Babies who are having more than 500ml (about a pint) of infant formula a day shouldn't be given vitamin supplements because formula is fortified with certain nutrients and no other supplementation is required.

Vitamin A is dangerous, potentially fatal, in overdose so follow carefully the dosing instructions.

Most children get enough iron. If the child isn't getting enough iron current recommendations are to modify the diet. In some situations that's not possible, so iron supplementation might be needed. This is something you should talk to a doctor about.

One thing you need to be aware of is the amount of supplementation of food in your country. In the US some milk has added vitamin D; in the UK flour has some nutrients added.